# Simple collision with .bmp's in an 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c++, collision

so I'm making a really simple program in which I want one sprite to collide with another.
I made a 'level' by making a grid with images, using a two-dimensional array.
How would I implement simple collision? I would appreciate coding examples, so I can actually see
what's going on. Thanks. Here's the code:

```
int pacmanPosX = 32;
int pacmanPosY = 32;

Sprite pacman (new Surface( "assets/tiles/pacman.png"), 1);

Surface* tileSet[2];
int landTile[14][16] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,}};


void Game::Init()
{
   // put your initialization code here; will be executed once
   tileSet[0] = new Surface( "assets/tiles/void.bmp" ); // Sets up data for tileSet
   tileSet[1] = new Surface( "assets/tiles/wall.bmp" );

}

void Game::Tick( float a_DT )
{
        m_Screen->Clear( 0 );

    for (int indexX = 0; indexX <= 14; indexX++)
    {
        for (int indexY = 0; indexY <= 16; indexY++)
        {
            int tile = landTile[indexY][indexX];
            tileSet[tile]->CopyTo( m_Screen, indexX * 32, indexY * 32 );
        }
    }

    pacman.Draw(pacmanPosX, pacmanPosY, m_Screen);



    Sleep( 10 );

int colPosX =  pacmanPosX    / 32; 
int colPosY = (pacmanPosY-1) / 32; 

bool collision = (bool)landTile[colPosX][colPosY]; 


int direction;

if(collision = false)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_UP )) pacmanPosY -=2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_DOWN ))  pacmanPosY += 2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_RIGHT )) pacmanPosX += 2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_LEFT ))  pacmanPosX -= 2;
}


}
```

That doesn't work, the character can't move at all now. For your information, every sprite is
32x32, including the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you calculate the position of the pacman to correspond to the landTitle array by dividing the pacmanPosX and pacmanPosY with the size of each square (32) and then cast it to an int. then you could simply check if the position in front of you is set to 1 or 0 in the landTile and in that way you can get a very simple and fast collision.

Tell me if you get into any hindrance

**EDIT**

What I mean is that you an array that explains where all the walls should be in your map. Because of that you don't have to do any sprite collision, instead you can do a simple collision check based on where you are supposed to be in the array. Lets consider the case where you are supposed to move up on the map:

```
int colPosX =  pacmanPosX    / 32;
int colPosY = (pacmanPosY-1) / 32;

bool collision = (bool)landTitle[colPosX][colPosY];
```

if *collision* is true then you have a collision one pixel upwards from your position, thats what the *-1* in the calculation of *colPosY* is for.

**Edit 2**

If i should edit your code then I would do it more like this

```
int blockSize = 32;
int pacmanPosX = blockSize * 1;
int pacmanPosY = blockSize * 1;

Sprite pacman (new Surface( "assets/tiles/pacman.png"), 1);

Surface* tileSet[2];
int landTile[14][16] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,}};


void Game::Init()
{
   // put your initialization code here; will be executed once
   tileSet[0] = new Surface( "assets/tiles/void.bmp" ); // Sets up data for tileSet
   tileSet[1] = new Surface( "assets/tiles/wall.bmp" );

}

void Game::Tick( float a_DT )
{
        m_Screen->Clear( 0 );

    for (int indexX = 0; indexX <= 14; indexX++)
    {
        for (int indexY = 0; indexY <= 16; indexY++)
        {
            int tile = landTile[indexY][indexX];
            tileSet[tile]->CopyTo( m_Screen, indexX * blockSize, indexY * blockSize );
        }
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_UP )    && CheckCollision(0,-1)) pacmanPosY -=2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_DOWN )  && CheckCollision(0, 1)) pacmanPosY += 2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_RIGHT ) && CheckCollision(1, 0)) pacmanPosX += 2;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState( VK_LEFT )  && CheckCollision(-1,0)) pacmanPosX -= 2;

    Sleep( 10 );
}

bool Game::CheckCollision(int dirX, int dirY){
    return (bool)landTile[(pacmanPosX+dirX)/blockSize][(pacmanPosY+dirY)/blockSize];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The only thing I can get out of that is the following:                                                  bool collision = false;

int pacmanposition = (pacmanPosX/32) + (pacmanPosX /32);

if(pacmanposition = landTile[1]) //That's the tile that should be solid.
{
collision = true;
}
I won't even try that. I just don't really know what I'm doing here, it is too abstract to me, somehow. I never expected this to be more difficult than pointers and classes and all that to me.

Comment: Sorry if I come off dense, but why the divide by 32 part? And I don't get the last ...=(bool)landtitle[colPosx][colPosY] line. I've never seen a bool used in braces before an array like that. This pretty frustrating now, this shouldn't be so difficult. I still don't get any of this. Oh, check my the end of my question... there seems to be a logical error in your code.

Comment: You have to divide it by 32 in order to map it to the size of the array. With that array you have made the map out of block of size 32 as you do in this line "tileSet[tile]->CopyTo( m_Screen, indexX * 32, indexY * 32 );" and in order to get back to index the array then you have to divide the position with 32 again

Comment: the (bool) part is a typecast to change the int value returned from landTitle to a bool, and you can't just insert that code right away =P

Comment: The size of my array is 14x16=224, right? How does dividing my character's position by his own width 'map it' to 224? And why would I want to do that anyway? My school isn't explaining ANY of this in their documents, so I'm walking in the dark here. I'm a complete noob if you didn't figured that out yet. Do you know of some tutorial that explaines this step by step, because I couldn't find any.

Comment: Your array is a 2D array of size 14 and 16 and that array is what's describing what your world looks like. When you draw your world you draw every block indexed to the both sizes in that array and multiplay it with 32. So position [1][1] in the array is at postion 32 and 32 while the position [1][2] is at position 32 and 64. If your character position is at lets say, x 154 and y 324 then if you divide it with 32 you will get (rounded down) 4 and 10. if you look up position [4][10] in your array you will get a '0' and if you cast a '0' to a bool you will get 'false' and then its no collision

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4196/discussion-between-udrian-and-turbosheep)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense... But why is the code not working, then? Did I implement it incorrectly? I added that colission has to be true in order for the up arrow key event to execute.